# performance improvements to database table

Tags: sql, performance, sql-server-2008

I have the following sql server 2008 database table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[cache](
[cache_key] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
[cache_data] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
[expiry_date] [datetime] NOT NULL) ON [PRIMARY]
```

I want to add a primary key to it, ie. make the cache_key column the primary key. This column contains unique strings. My question is, are there any implications to making a nvarchar 50 column a primary key? Is it possible to add primary key to this column that contains data, even if the cache_key data is unique?

I also have another script that runs each day that removes data from the table based on the expiry_date column. This could mean up to 5000 records deleted based upon comparison to this field. Would it help performance if I created an index on this field?

Answer (score 1):

You can make a primary key out of anything that's indexable and unique. A varchar(50) is no problem. You can add define a primary key after the fact, as long as every record has a unique value in that column. YOu won't be allowed to "primary-ize" a column(s) that isn't unique.

As for the index, if it only ever gets referenced in a single delete query that runs once a day, then don't bother indexing it. The overhead of maintaining the index through every single insert/update on the table won't be worth the microscopic time savings you'd get on the once-a-day delete. On the other hand, if that field is used frequently in where/join clauses in other queries, then go ahead and put on a index - you'll definitely improve performance.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, technically, you can make any column that is less than 900 bytes in maximum size your primary key, e.g. you cannot make a `NVARCHAR(2000)` your primary key, but a `nvarchar(50)` works.

The requirements for the primary key are:

- must be unique
- must not be NULL

If those requirements are met - you're good to go.

One thing to keep in mind is this: your primary key is - by default - also your clustering key, the key by which the table's contents is physically ordered (slightly simplified). As such, that clustering key is like the *address* or *pointer* of your data row in the table, and it will be included into each and every non-clustered index you have on your table, too.

If you have a table that doesn't have any or just a single non-clustered index - no worries. But if your table has quite a few nonclustered indices (like a `Customer` table which might have four, five indices or even more), than having such a wide clustering key (100 bytes) of variable width is not ideal. In this case, you're better off using something like an `INT IDENTITY` as your surrogate key, and put your primary key / clustered index onto that column. It will save you **a lot** of disk space and make your table perform much better.

Read more about what makes a good clustering key (on a busy, large table) in Kimberly Tripp's blog post [Ever-increasing clustering key - the Clustered Index Debate..........again!](http://www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/KIMBERLY/post/Ever-increasing-clustering-key-the-Clustered-Index-Debateagain!.aspx) - highly educational!